# Не подключается аккаунт для GoogleApiClient в debug режиме

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play-services

Использую Xamarin в Visual Studio. Пытаюсь в debug режиме подключить GoogleApiClient, но при выборе аккаунта в OnActivityResult постоянно получаю Result.Canceled. В release версии все работает нормально. Пожалуйста направьте в нужном направлении, как можно в debug режиме подключиться.

```
    [Activity(Label = "Label")]
public class GoogleDriveActivity : Activity, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
{
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private EditText editFileName;
    private Button btnSave;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GoogleDriveSave);
        int result = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result == ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .AddApi(DriveClass.API)
                .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeFile)
                .AddScope (DriveClass.ScopeAppfolder)
                .UseDefaultAccount()
                .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .Build();

        }
        else
        {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(result))
            {
                GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).Show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        googleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    override protected void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        googleApiClient.Disconnect();
    }

    public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {

    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Suspended: {0}", cause);
    }

    public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        if (result.HasResolution && result.ErrorCode == 4) // SIGN_IN_REQUIRED
        {
            try
            {
                result.StartResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex)
            {
                // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.GetErrorDialog(result.ErrorCode, this, 0).Show();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                googleApiClient.Connect();
            else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```